# Xcode: Can't create snapshot - This file does not exist in the index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am trying to create a snapshot in Xcode 4, and I keep on getting the error "This file does not exist in the index." and it says it can't create a snapshot. When I press ok, it has the progress bar for creating a snapshot and doesn't do anything else.

[image: Error dialog]

Comment: Git uses something called an index, it's possible that the snapshot code is confused by git being in an inconsistent state.  Is your project using Git?

Comment: Hi Jim yes it is... Hmm perhaps i should commit first?

Answer (score -3):

I am guessing this is happening when using the simulator. This happened to me a while back. Use this program:

http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/

IOS-Simulator cropper is a great tool to take screenshots of the simulator. It will let you save the file anywhere and also gives you the option to save only the screen image or with the iphone border. It is byfar the best screen shot program for the iphone simulator I have found. If your not using the simulator, just press the sleep button and the home button at the same time and the picture will be saved to your camera app

Comment: No it's taking a snapshot automatically because it's going to convert the code to ARC for version five. So it fails in the first step.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea why this would happen. I don't know what else to say. Sorry I couldn't help.